# How to launch Login Activity for once after successful login?

Tags: android

I have a **splash screen**, which, after few m-seconds opens a **Login Activity**. I would like that, when the user clicks the **login button**,  and the login is successful, the next time the user opens the app the **splash screen** should open **Main Activity** instead of **Login Activity**. How can I do that?

SplashScreen

```
 Thread timer = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
      }
```

LoginActivity

```
_loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });

 public void login(){
    name = _nameText.getText().toString();
    password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(LoginActivity.this);
    res = myDb.getData(name,password);

    if (res == true) {
        onLoginSuccess();
     } else {
        onLoginFailed();
     }         
}

    public void onLoginSuccess() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use `SharedPreferences` to store the username and password. Then when the user opens the app again, it can check for these values and log the user in automatically.

So when the user logs in successfully:

```
public void onLoginSuccess() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username", _nameText.getText().toString();
    // this should be salted
    editor.putString("password", _passwordText.getText().toString();
    editor.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will save the username and password.

Then to check for stored values, you would do something like this in the `onCreate`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userName = sharedPreferences.getString("username", null);
String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
if (userName != null && password != null ) {
    doLogin(userName, password);
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to use sharedPreferences in right way, can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Actually, if you are already in an activity, you don't need context. You can just call `getSharedPreferences`. I updated my answer

Comment: +1 for using SharedPreferences. -1 for suggesting that the OP save the password. **Never ever store raw passwords - they only belong in the user's head**.

Comment: That is right. You should salt it. Thanks @adelphus

Comment: @mattfred I am getting an error after removing context that create a method for getSharedPreferences

Comment: add `getApplicationContext()` like this `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences`

Comment: @mattfred I am having an error that getSharedPreferences in Context can not be applied to (int)

Comment: You need to add a name for your shared preference file `getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: @mattfred Where should i use the second code, i mean to say in splash screen or in login activity?

Comment: Either would be fine. You could use it in the splash screen. If the login data is valid, it would then go directly to the main activity. Or, when the login activity shows, it gets the login data, logs the user in and then goes to the main activity.

Comment: @mattfred what is doLogin?

Comment: That is a method you need to write. It is going to use the same login logic that you used in the onClick method. This time it is being done without the button click though.

Comment: @mattfred You mean I should write this res = myDb.getData(name,password);

Comment: @mattfred FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 11588
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.DatabaseHelper.getData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

Comment: @mattfred I did this, but still I am getting the login screen again and agian

Comment: @mattfred I tried it many times at last it worked, actually i was making mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Shared Preferences to store boolean value   true/false , login id , password. When clicked login for the first time save those vales in shared preference and next time when ever application launches in splash screen do background shared preference check of boolean value loggedin or not. If yes then either directly send to Main Activity or automatically pass saved id, passwodd to login method for proper auto login.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this? Actually I am new to android.

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm This link is exactly what you want. See the example in this link

Comment: Did this link helped solving your question ?

Comment: yes, I have made it through the link you provided, this was exactly what i needed, Now I understand it completely..

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of the SharedPreferences.

When the user has successful logged in, simply save the value "true" for "successful logged in". And make a simple check before your intent. You can specify a default value, which should be false. If the value is true, start another intent.

This could look something like:

```
public class Preferences {

private static final String LOGGED_IN = "LOGGED_STATE",
private final Context context;

    public Preferences(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean getLoggedIn() {
        return getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(LOGGED_IN, false);
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean state) {
        getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean(LOGGED_IN, state).apply();
    }
}
```

For checking if the user has already logged in use the getLoggedIn method. 
Otherwise, if return value is false and user must logg in. Use the setLoggedIn method to save the state in the app.

I hope I was able to help you.

EDIT:

SplashScreen in your Thread

```
Preferences pref = new Preferences(context);

Intent intent = null;

if (pref.getLoggedIn) {     //if true = yes successful logged in before 
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {                            //(default = false, not logged in)
    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    SplashScreen.this.finish();  //What's this?
}
```

LoginActivity

```
Preferences pref = new Preferences(context);

public void login(){
    name = _nameText.getText().toString();
    password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(LoginActivity.this);
    res = myDb.getData(name,password);

    if (res == true) {
        pref.setLoggedIn(true);
     } else {
       pref.setLoggedIn(false); 
     }
```

You may have to edit a small things, but this should show you the principle.

Comment: SplashSreen.this.finish(); it finishes the splash screen so that  user could not go back to splash screen on pressing back button.

Comment: Okay, doesn't have then a influence to the rest/ the answer to your question.

Comment: I am going to insert your code, I hope that it will work.

Comment: I'm still a beginner too. I recommend just to understand the principle and adapt it then. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is creating a Session Manager class where you can do methods to handle the SharedPreferences.

Check the tutorial above, it has exactly what you need because it also uses SplashActivity:

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/12/session-management-in-android-example.html